# How to give an array in storage value from an array from a function's input parameters

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, memory

Below is the code that I have:

```
struct Cow{
    uint age;
    uint name;
}

Cow[] cows;

// this is the code I am trying below.
function createCows(Cow[] memory _cows) public {
    cows =_cows;
}
```

When I try the code above I get an error:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.Cow memory[]
> memory to storage not yet supported.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to achieve without using a loop?